# Redirect from Web query open agent on Lotus Domino?

Tags: redirect, lotus-notes, agent, lotus-domino

Does anyone know a way of redirecting to another webpage from lotus domino web query an open agent? The print statement does not seem to work. A possible workaround would be very appreciated!

Something on that subject can be found here but it seems kind of flaky like this
[link](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/46dom.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/552ac51dccd42ac785256adc0054f7fc?OpenDocument).

Can it be done without JavaScript and major redesign of document form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that the 4/5 forum is almost a decade out-of-date, right? If you're using a more recent version of Notes/Domino, I'd check the 6/7 forum (or even the 8 if you're on that release, since it's so different); here's the search results for "webqueryopen redirect"; there are a lot more possible answers.

[Notes 6/7 forum results](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/Search?SearchView&Query=webqueryopen%20redirect&SearchOrder=0&Start=1&Count=100/)

The simplest answers to your actual question are [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/ce98a7b9e9d0c0da852572b4004305e0?OpenDocument) and [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/00d889f1d12dd5268525755200315065?OpenDocument).

Comment: Offcourse, but the problem is still actual. Even on LND 8.5.2!

Comment: But thnx for links, they all amount to something and I think I found an even easier solution and it is a one liner in WQO agent:

 Call s.Documentcontext.Replaceitemvalue("$$HTMLHead", {<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.etfos.hr">"})

Comment: No design changes or anything just this code. But it still loads the page first. But that is not to bad.

Answer (score 1):

Better to wite to 'location:' header directly, as avoids Javascript and meta-tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is from one of the responses on the thread you pointed to and should work fine - have the WQO agent simply write to a hidden field on the form. This will do a client-side redirect, so you'll get two trips to the server.

> You could use your WQO to set a field
>   on the document called redirect. Set
>   the field to text and hide it from
>   everything. HEre's what you put in the
>   field (with your WQO agent):
>   location.replace('http://www.website.com');
>
> In your HtmlHeadContent, put this
>   formula:
>
> "" +
>   @NewLine + redirect + @NewLine +
>   ""

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion does not work. It only prints the stuff you put in HTML head content but no redirect.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by adding the following code to body onLoad event:

Comment: try {
var redir = document.getElementById("redirect").value;
location.replace(redir);
}catch(e) {alert (e.message);}

Comment: This works but it shows the content of the page for a moment and then redirects.

Answer (score 0):

A line of code in WQO agent does the trick, but note it still loads the page before the redirect:

`Call s.Documentcontext.Replaceitemvalue("$$HTMLHead", {<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.etfos.hr">"})`

Comment: Meta refresh is discouraged by the W3C. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Usability

Answer (score 0):

in your agent, simply do the following
print |[| & requiredURL & |]|

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if you really need to open the document instead of running an agent and pass the params in the Query_String

I think that wqo cannot redirect to another page as it will end up redirecting you to the document you either opened or are creating.  I may be wrong but yesterday I was trying to either do one thing or the other based on the params I was passing to the OpenCorm url command and it seems that although it is running the agent, the pw.println() command doesn't behave the same as if it was a WQS agent.

If you don't need to open a document, try running an agent and pass the params to it

Answer (score -1):

The proper way to do it is to have one print statement with the URL you want to redirect to in brackets. This will generate a 302 REDIRECT on the server.

Example code:

```
%REM
    Agent redirect
    Trigger: On Schedule - Never
    Target: None
    Security Level: 1
%END REM
Option Public
Option Declare

Sub Initialize
    Print "[http://www.ibm.com]"
End Sub
```

Some people have suggested Meta Refresh. This is discouraged by the W3C. See the following link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Usability

Comment: I think he is right saying that Print does not have any effect in WebQueryOpen agent.

Comment: ahhh! Yes. Doh. :/ Will check later, although this appears to be a bumped question.